# App store connect, missing input for URL for App Store server notifications

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I need to update URL for App Store server notifications, which I entered when started development the app.
So IT was available.
But now, there is no such input

Also I have valid role for edit this info, have several Auto-Renewable Subscriptions, used different browsers. and my teammates do not see this input too

as describe in doc https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev0067a330b

[image]

Comment: I am seeing this too

Comment: Hi , I'm also facing the same issue. Any idea or suggestions ?

Comment: @ManojArunS check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written to apple support and got the answer with "To better assist you, I need more information. Please provide the following:...."

So I started recording the video about this issue and guess what? Right! The input field was in the place where it should be.

I did nothing additional after write this  post and ask the support. Dark magic as it is.

Apple should improve developer experience in App Store Connect. This is not the first such problem. The most often, apple even does not the error text and you should go to dev tools and look out what the real problem

Answer (score 10):

You have to add a subscription item in your In App Purchases Section.

[image]

Once added the field will show up.